# differences between photelectric amplifier and optical amplifier?

Tags: amplifier, proximity-sensor, optical-fibre

i'm researching about fiber optic sensor and stumbled upon a question regarding about the amplifier. I've read in the internet that optical amplififer contained many type such as EDFA,semi-conductor and raman. While, on the other hand, photoelectric amplifier has scarce information about them. Both of them are related to fiber optic but to me it seems like there are two category where the optical amplifier is for telecommunication while photoelectric amplifier is for industrial sensor. Maybe someone can give me a clear explanation whether these two are the same or not and what are their working principle?

Answer (score 0):

They simply have two different purposes.

Optical amplifier is a repeater - it boosts the optical signal, to drive the next length of fibre.

Photoelectric is a detector. It's used in telecom as well as industrial - at the point where you're leaving the optical domain for the electrical (e.g. for processing, routing, or RF such as cellphone transmission - or simply to hear the phone call).

As such, you can add LASER diode to the list - it's a Light Amplifier for signals coming from the electrical domain.